# How to use the method literal_processor of sqlalchemy dialect types?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, clickhouse

The usage of this method for types is not obvious. I have read the `sqlalchemy` documentation where it is said that the method is used to render a query part directly from literal values. But I do not understand when it may be called for types.

For instance, let us take `clickhouse_sqlalchemy.types.Array`. Its method looks this way:

```py
def literal_processor(self, dialect):
    item_processor = self.item_type_impl.literal_processor(dialect)

    def process(value):
        processed_value = []
        for x in value:
            if item_processor:
                x = item_processor(x)
            processed_value.append(x)
        return '[' + ', '.join(processed_value) + ']'
    return process
```

It is explicitly seen, that the method returns a function rendering usual **ClickHouse** array like `[1, 2, 3]`. But how can I achieve this in a query? I used `Array` only as a type for casting, for example, `sa.cast(sa.func.array(1, 2, 3), Array(String))`, and could not use it in any other way to create native **ClickHouse** arrays in query renders.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand the question, but you can always cast a string that "looks like" an array into ClickHouse's Array like this:

```
clickhouse-cloud :) select '[1, 2, 3]'::String as col_str, toTypeName(col_str) as col_str_type, col_str::Array(UInt32) as col_str_cast_array_uint32, toTypeName(col_str_cast_array_uint32) as col_array_type

SELECT
    CAST('[1, 2, 3]', 'String') AS col_str,
    toTypeName(col_str) AS col_str_type,
    CAST(col_str, 'Array(UInt32)') AS col_str_cast_array_uint32,
    toTypeName(col_str_cast_array_uint32) AS col_array_type

Query id: 200abba4-2fd1-4cc3-9efe-529765c26a09

┌─col_str───┬─col_str_type─┬─col_str_cast_array_uint32─┬─col_array_type─┐
│ [1, 2, 3] │ String       │ [1,2,3]                   │ Array(UInt32)  │
└───────────┴──────────────┴───────────────────────────┴────────────────┘

1 row in set. Elapsed: 0.001 sec.
```